# How to assess differential risk of disease across three groups after adjusting for other risk factors?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, spss

I have 3 different groups: A, B, and C:

- A (has a medical condition) has 30 entries
- B (another medical condition) has 31 entries
- C (control group) has 55 entries

All participants have information on the same set of variables.

I want to assess whether there is a statistically significant difference in risk of a specific disease between:

- Group A and C
- Group B and C
- Group B and A

Also, all groups need to be adjusted for other known risk factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logistic regression.  In SPSS the categorical variable (group A, B, or C) can be entered as a single variable using the contrast command, in which case one of the three will be designated as the reference category, or if you prefer you can create 2 dummy variables to account for the 3 groups.

You would run the regression hierarchically:  first enter those risk factors you want to control, then on a separate step enter Group and watch for the coefficients, odds ratios [in SPSS, "Exp(B)"], and/or p-values you obtain for each category as compared to the reference category.  For example, if C is the reference and if the odds ratio for A is 1.3, then A has 1.3 times the odds that C has of developing the disease.  (Just be careful to distinguish odds from probability.)